# Windows detected threat HackTool:SH/PythonKeylogger.B after using pynput

Tags: python

I use Windows 10 and recently I'm learning to use the pynput module in Python. After writing a script that records all alphabet keys the user pressed, Windows Security showed that a threat named `HackTool:SH/PythonKeylogger.B` had been detected, then my script was removed.

Does this mean my device has been infected by a virus, or my script had been mistaken by Windows as a virus?

From Windows Security:

```
Threat blocked  High
13/06/2022 21:07

Detected: HackTool:SH/PythonKeylogger.B
Status: Quarantined
Quarantined files are in a restricted area where they can't harm your device.
They will be removed automatically.

Date: 13/06/2022 21:08
Details: This program has potentially unwanted behaviour

Affected items:
  file: (my python script)
```

Comment: It seems extremely likely windows security flagged your own script, as the function of the script could be seen as suspicious and the affected item points to your own script.

Comment: As that library monitors the input of your input devices, it could be used to make a keylogger, and therefore Windows Defender (most likely) thought it's a keylogger (as stated by `PythonKeylogger.B`). You should be safe to dequarantine your own script, and you have most likely be NOT infected by a virus. It's most likely a false positiv.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But is it possible or is it a good idea to tell Windows Security to ignore certain files (scripts that I'm working on) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any sensible antivirus will detect key logging as a suspicious activity.

to solve this problem you should except only your own files from this error as this threat can be very harmful to if it's a real malware.

the steps are :

1.press windows key then print Virus & threat protection

2.you will see a title named Virus & threat protection settings press the blue link under it wich says manage settings

3.you will see a title named exclusions press the blue link under it wich says add or remove exclusion

4.press add an exclusion and add a folder, then you can add the file you want to this folder and run it

!!Note: if you want to only exclude the file you should follow the step no 4 first the remove the folder exclusion after excluding the specific file
I hope my answer was helpful